# stop bash script from outputting in terminal

Tags: bash, if-statement

I believe I have everything setup correctly for my if else statement however it keeps outputting content into my shell terminal as if i ran the command myself. is there anyway i can escape this so i can run these commands without it populating my terminal with text from the results?

```
#!/bin/bash
ps cax | grep python > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Process is running." &
  echo $!
else
  echo "Process is not running... Starting..."
  python likebot.py &
  echo $!
fi
```

Here is what the output looks like a few minutes after running my bash script

```
[~]# sh check.sh
Process is not running... Starting...
12359
[~]# Your account has been rated. Sleeping on kranze for 1 minute(s). Liked 0 photo(s)...
Your account has been rated. Sleeping on kranze for 2 minute(s). Liked 0 photo(s)...
```

Comment: What in the output don't you want to see anymore?

Comment: Just a question: What is the behaviour you are expecting here `echo "Process is running." & echo $!`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to redirect output from within the shell script, you use exec:

```
exec 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

This will redirect everything from now on.  If you want to output to a log:

```
exec 1>/tmp/logfile 2>&1
```

To append a log:

```
exec 1>>/tmp/logfile 2>&1
```

To backup your handles so you can restore them:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2
exec 1>/dev/null 2>&1

# Do some stuff

# Restore descriptors
exec 1>&3 2>&4

# Close the descriptors.
exec 3>&- 4>&-
```

If there is a particular section of a script you want to silence:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Hey, check me out, I can make noise!

{
    echo Thats not fair, I am being silenced!
    mv -v /tmp/a /tmp/b

    echo Me too.
} 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect the "normal (stdout)" output use `>/dev/null` if you also want to redirect the error output as well use `2>&1 >/dev/null`

eg

```
$ command 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to redirect STDOUT (and may be STDERR) of the python interpreter:

```
...
  echo "Process is not running... Starting..."
  python likebot.py >/dev/null 2>&1 &
...
```

For further details, please have a look at [Bash IO-Redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Hope that helped a bit.
*Jost

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- You can redirect standard output to a log file using `> /path/to/file`
- You can redirect standard output to `/dev/null` to get rid of it completely using `> /dev/null`

If you want error output redirected as well use `&>`

See [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

Also, not relevant to this particular example, but some bash commands support a 'quiet' or 'silent' flag.

Answer (score 0):

Append *>> /path/to/outputfile/outputfile.txt* to the end of every echo statement

```
echo "Process is running." >> /path/to/outputfile/outputfile.txt
```

Alternatively, send the output to the file when you run the script from the shell

```
 [~]# sh check.sh >> /path/to/outputfile/outputfile.txt
```

Comment: You don't need to do that.

Comment: @Craig You do propose a better approach-which you hadn't at the time I posted. What I suggested does work, your approach is merely better

Comment: @kakoma Your "solution" "works" in some situations, but it can also induce more bugs (like not having correct permissions etc). There are bad solutions and there are proper ones, yours is the former.

Comment: @Jite I believe my comment acknowledges that. Thanks Craig